# Restricting Slideshow CK to certain pages within Joomla

Tags: joomla, slideshow

I am trying to show Slideshow CK only on the homepage of my Joomla based site. I have gone into the 'assignment' section of the module and restricted it to 'Home' menu item and said 'no' to include on child items. This works fine. I only see the slideshow on my homepage. However, I have created a link to an article on one of my other menus. When that article is displayed, it shows the slideshow. I want to suppress it when it jumps to that link. I have been playing with various options but without much joy. I would appreciate it if somebody can clarify the control mechanism for selectively displaying the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method of overcoming the problem but someone may suggest a better approach. I specifically went and excluded certain selected articles in the assignments. I had tried to exclude a 'hidden' category but that did not work for me. The downside of my approach is that every time I introduce a new article I have to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are creating articles without menu items. Without a menu item you won't be able to control the module assignment so easily.

If you're comfortable editing your template an lternative approach would be to amend the template and load the module.

1. Locate the index.php file of your template. You should be able to do this via the template manager.
2. Create a custom module position e.g. slideshow-ck and assign the slideshow module only to the homepage.
3. Then in the template you would need to add some PHP as follows:

   ```
   <?php 
     $menu = $app->getMenu();
     $active = $menu->getActive(); 
     if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault('en-GB')) && $this->countModules('slideshow-ck') ?>
       <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slideshow-ck" style="html5" />
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Basically what that does is only load the module position if it's assigned to the menu item AND the user is currently viewing the homepage.

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page